# javascript/framework7 autocomplete Umlaut

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, html-framework-7

when adding a string with an 'Umlaut', e.g 'Äpfel' by '&Aumlpfel' to a list to be shown in a autocomplete-drop down list, the Umlaut is shown properly ('Äpfel') in the dropped down list, but not, once it is selected '&Aumlpfel'.

What am I missing, please? 
Please note the code below. Any help is much appreciated.

```
   <head>
      <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 1, 
         maximum-scale = 1, minimum-scale = 1, user-scalable = no, minimal-ui" />
      <meta name = "apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content = "yes" />
      <meta name = "apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content = "black" />
      <title>Autocomplete</title>
      <link rel = "stylesheet" 
         href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/framework7/1.4.2/css/framework7.ios.min.css" />
      <link rel = "stylesheet" 
         href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/framework7/1.4.2/css/framework7.ios.colors.min.css" />
   </head>

   <body>
      <div class = "views">
         <div class = "view view-main">
            <div class = "pages">
               <div data-page = "home" class = "page navbar-fixed">

                  <div class = "navbar">
                     <div class = "navbar-inner">
                        <div class = "left"> </div>
                        <div class = "center">Autcomplete</div>
                        <div class = "right"> </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class = "page-content">

                     <div class = "content-block-title">Dropdown With All Values</div>
                     <div class = "list-block">
                        <ul>
                           <li class = "item-content">
                              <div class = "item-title label">Fruits</div>
                              <div class = "item-input">
                                 <input type = "text" placeholder = "Fruits" id = "autocomplete-dropdown-all">
                              </div>
                           </li>
                        </ul>
                     </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>

      <script type  =  "text/javascript" 
         src  =  "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/framework7/1.4.2/js/framework7.min.js"></script>

      <script>
         var myApp  =  new Framework7();
         var $$  =  Dom7;
         var mainView  =  myApp.addView('.view-main');

         // Countries data array
         var fruits  =  ('Apples &Aumlpfel').split(' ');


         // Dropdown with all values
         var autocompleteDropdownAll = myApp.autocomplete ({
            input: '#autocomplete-dropdown-all',
            openIn: 'dropdown',

            source: function (autocomplete, query, render) {
               var results = [];

               // You can find matched items
               for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
                  if (fruits[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) >= 0) 
                     results.push(fruits[i]);
               }
               // Display the items by passing array with result items
               render(results);
            }
         });


      </script>
   </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

is missing in the header. Then there is no need for the html type of Umlaut

Comment: I have the same issue, but I do have the meta charset entry in the header. Could you fix it?

Comment: it must be something different, as I found out that the query string should be "Apfel" and not "Äpfel". So something in framework7 seems to normalize accents, which makes it hard to compare...

Answer (score 0):

Framework7 seems to alter the query by replacing umlauts with its accent free character. So, typing "Äpfel" seems to send the query "Apfel" in framework7, which makes it hard to compare.

I solved it by overriding the query string, getting the original query from the searchbar value:

```
source: function (autocomplete, query, render) {
  var results = [];
  query = $("#autocomplete-dropdown-all")[0].value || query;
  ...
```